# Can I use groovy's default getters / setters to help implement a java interface?

Tags: java, groovy, setter, getter, getter-setter

I am extending a very simple Java interface from an imported library. The interface is so simple that the only methods it declares are getters and setters for a list of properties.

My application is written in Groovy, so I'd like to implement this Java interface with a Groovy class.

I was under the impression that Groovy created getters and setters by default for any of its classes' properties - can I use these default getters and setters to satisfy the Java interface's requirements?

Library's Java interface:

```
public interface Animal {  // java interface
    public String getName();
    public void setName(String name);
    public Integer getAge();
    public void setAge(Integer age);
}
```

I hoped I'd be able to implement it like this with Groovy (but my compiler is complaining about missing setters):

```
public class Cat implements Animal { // Groovy class
    public String name;
    public Integer age;
}
```

Comment: Which compiler is complaining? What is the error?

Comment: Also, what's the exact interface?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.groovy-lang.org/differences.html#_package_scope_visibility) out. I'm not a groovy dev, but I stumbled across it a couple days ago. I think you have to remove the access modifier for it to become a property (with getter/setter)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do that with groovy *properties*, but take into account the difference between *[fields and properties](http://www.groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#_fields_and_properties)*:

> A **field** is a member of a class or a trait which:
>
> - a mandatory access modifier (public, protected, or private)
> - one or more optional modifiers (static, final, synchronized)
> - an optional type
> - a mandatory name

[...]

> A **property** is a combination of a private field and getters/setters.
>   You can define a property with:
>
> - an **absent** access modifier (no public, protected or final)
> - one or more optional modifiers (static, final, synchronized)
> - an optional type
> - a mandatory name
>
> Groovy will then generate the getters/setters appropriately.

When you put an explicit access modifier, you are actually using a field, so getters/setters are not generated and that's why the compiler complains about `Can't have an abstract method in a non-abstract class`, since getters/setters are not there.