# How can I use Groovy's properties in Interfaces?

Tags: groovy, properties

Let's say I have defined an Interface in Groovy (with properties) like this:

```
public interface GroovyInterface
{       
    int intProperty;       
    boolean boolProperty;
}
```

Then I implement the Interface:

```
public class GroovyImplementation implements GroovyInterface
{
    // How do I implement the properties here?        
}
```

How would I now implement the properties in the concrete class? `@Override` doesn't work, since IntelliJ complains that I can't override a field.
I've read [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107148/can-i-use-groovys-default-getters-setters-to-help-implement-a-java-interface), but it only says that it is possible to use properties in an Interface, but not *how*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like in Java you cannot specify properties in an interface. But with Groovy you can use a trait for that:

```
trait GroovyInterface
{
    int intProperty
    boolean boolProperty
}
```

You can then use it exactly like an interface with "implements GroovyInterface".

For more information on traits consult http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-traits.html